# Javascript Set Attribute With Single Quotation

Tags: javascript

It seems that by default javascript appends attributes using double quotes. However in my situation I am attempting to append a json string to a data attribute and the double quote interferes with the json.

```
var json = {"foo":"bar"}
var el = document.getElementById("someElement");
el.setAttribute("data-json", JSON.stringify(json)); //<div data-json="{"foo":"bar"}">
```

How can I append an attribute using a single quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is incorrect to say that

> by default javascript appends attributes using double quotes.

An attribute is merely a string. The attribute value itself does not include the surrounding quotes. Quotes are nothing more than syntax for representing a string literal. The outside quotes you see surrounding the attribute in

```
<div data-json="{"foo":"bar"}">
```

do not exist in the attribute value; they were simply inserted by the console when it is printing out the attribute for your visual convenience. There is nothing "interfering with the JSON". The attribute value can be retrieved and parsed with `JSON.parse` as is with no further ado.

```
var json = {"foo":"bar"}
var el = document.getElementById("someElement");
el.setAttribute("data-json", JSON.stringify(json));

// now, parse the attribute
>> JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-json'))
<< Object {foo: "bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better practice is string escaping (see [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738304/930170)).

But just as an other option you may be able to replace double quotes with single quotes by `.replace()` function:

```
var json = {"foo":"bar"}

var encoded = JSON.stringify(json);
encoded = encoded.replace(/\\"/g, '"')
    .replace(/([\{|:|,])(?:[\s]*)(")/g, "$1'")
    .replace(/(?:[\s]*)(?:")([\}|,|:])/g, "'$1")
    .replace(/([^\{|:|,])(?:')([^\}|,|:])/g, "$1\\'$2");

var el = document.getElementById("someElement");
el.setAttribute("data-json", encoded);
```

**Attention** the result string `"{'foo':'bar'}"` is not a valid json

Comment: I don't think json can use single quotes. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess I could replace the double quotes upon retrieval but i'm back to the same issue with the escape method.

Comment: Yes, you right. I'm wrote about this in the bottom of answer. I'm add this answer just as option, cause @ryandlf ask exactly about single quotes. The string escaping is better

Comment: Why do I need to do this? People have been storing stringified JSON in element attributes, and then parsing it back, for eons without the kind of transformation you mention. There is a fundamental misunderstanding that the attribute setting is somehow adding surrounding quotes to the string, which is incorrect. As I mentioned in my answer, those quotes are nothing more than a display artifact.